# Expose mutable C++ object (float) to boost python

Tags: python, c++, boost, game-engine, mutable

I would like to expose a float object from my C++ code, to a boost python module. My current attempt looks like this:

```
float timeInterval = 0.0f;
... 
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(engine)
{
    scope().attr("timeInterval") = object(ptr(&timeInterval));
    ...
}
```

I found an example like this here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/HowTo#mutable_C.2B-.2B-_object however, this appears to be specifically used for class instances and not primitives? I'm wondering if I can expose a primitive variable in a similar manner and if so, how? I also tried to see if def_readwrite was available at module level, and its not.

Comment: what would be the difference with primitives in this respect?

Comment: They aren't instances of a class? As the example in the link I provided is. No call operator?

Comment: You lost me at "No call operator?". Perhaps it is obvious to a pythonista, so I'll assume I just miss the necessary background.

Comment: I thought you were trying to lead me to the answer vaguely lol. If you have any suggestions or ideas I'd love to hear them - still fighting this one.